# Google Sheets' clearContent() not consistent?

Tags: google-sheets-api

It's my first day using googlescript and I'm having a little trouble with the clearContent() method.  The data I am testing is one row normal, then bold, then normal again.  Like so:

First row.
**Second row.**
Third row.

When I run my code, it's clearing out the first row just how I want, then skips past the second row since it's bold.  However the third row is getting skipped too.  Any suggestions?  (Or am I just missing something silly?)

```
for (var row=1; row<=numRows; row++) {
  for (var column=1; column<=numCols; column++){
    //For debugging
    Browser.msgBox("(" + row + "," + column + ")|" + range.getCell(row, column).getValue() + "|" + range.getCell(row, column).getFontWeight() + "|", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if (values[row][column] != "" && range.getCell(row, column).getFontWeight() == "normal") {
      range.getCell(row, column).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After messing with the code a bit and assigning some variables this worked.  Not exactly sure why.

```
for (var row=1; row<=numRows; row++) {
    for (var column=1; column<=numCols; column++){
    value = range.getCell(row, column).getValue();
    fontWeight = range.getCell(row, column).getFontWeight();
    //For debugging
    //Browser.msgBox("(" + row + "," + column + ")|" + range.getCell(row, column).getValue() + "|" + range.getCell(row, column).getFontWeight() + "|", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if (value != "" && fontWeight == "normal") {
      range.getCell(row, column).clearContent();
    }else if (fontWeight == "bold") {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```